# Mean of rows and columns of matrices in a cell

Tags: matlab, cell, mean

I have say `n` `a x b` matrices and I want to generate a new matrix of dimension `a x b` which is the mean of all `n` `a x b` matrices, i.e the first element of this new matrix is the mean of all first elements in each `n` `a x b` matrices and so on. Is there a way to compute this average matrix from a group of matrices in MATLAB? I had tried to do this by creating a cell but couldn't figure out how to take mean of each element of these matrices. I would appreciate any ideas or suggestions.

Comment: Welcome to SO. Please add a [mcve] detailing your code, so we can take a look at it.

Comment: Why not put it in an a x b x n matrix and use the regular `mean`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First, put your n matrix in a single `axbxn` matrix

```
M = cat(3, mat1, mat2, mat3, ...);
```

Or, if you work with a cell array,

```
M = cat(3, cellOfMats{:})
```

Then just use mean along the third dimension

```
meanmat = mean(M,3)
```

Comment: as he has *"matrices in a cell"* -  `cat(3, cellOfMatrices{:})` should do.

Comment: Didn't added it at first because he said that it was only something that he "tried", good suggestion tho.